# flutter code painting Rect bottom line below screen - why (example attached)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-canvas

Why does the lower Rect line go below the screen even through I've aimed to calculate this?

[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        ),
        body: MainScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mq = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final logicWidth = mq.size.width;
    final logicHeight = mq.size.height;
    return 

    SizedBox.expand(
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
            child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.none,   // Can more to "contain" after
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: logicWidth,
                  height: logicHeight,
                  child: CustomPaint(painter: GCPainter(),),
                ))));
  }
}

class GCPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint1 = Paint()..color = Colors.red..style = PaintingStyle.stroke..strokeWidth = 50;
    Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint1);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(GCPainter oldDelegate) => false;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuildSemantics(GCPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: Does the MediaQuery work out the whole screen, not just the widget size.ie remove the size of the AppBar from the logicHeight.

Comment: @Glen - is there a way to get AppBar size?  Would I need to also take into account padding/viewInsets also available in MediaQuery too).

Comment: You can use PreferredSize to set set the appBar size. Not sure on other settings.

Comment: instead of `Container > FittedBox > SizedBox > CustomPaint` why dont you simply do `Container > CustomPaint > SizedBox.expand`?

Comment: was just based on a google video I saw and this article (https://stasheq.medium.com/scale-whole-app-or-widget-contents-to-a-screen-size-in-flutter-e3be161b5ab4) - but I'm just learning - key point was I realised I didn't understand what was happening exactly so pasted this question.

Comment: @pskink - so would you have SizedBox.expand in your CustomPainter?  or did you mean go:  Container>SizedBox.expand>CustomPaint?

Comment: this is what `build` should return: `Container > CustomPaint > SizedBox.expand` - you can add `print(size)` inside `GCPainter.paint` and run your code with and without `SizedBox.expand` and compare results

Comment: ok thanks I'll try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to manage your top and bottom area for notch or bottom control, [SafeArea](https://walkingtree.tech/safearea-flutter-widget/):

```
SafeArea(
 child: Container(),
 top: true,
 bottom: true,
)
```

Comment: thanks - but then setting my logical height I use I'd need to dynamically calcaulate this a different way then?   Would I need to complete the MediaQuery "size" and also subtract its "padding" (I see there are viewInsets and viewPadding too?)

Comment: or would there be a better way to dynamically get actual remaining size?

Comment: LayoutBuilder!  LayoutBuilder!  Never call MediaQuery for the size again!

Comment: @RandalSchwartz - I guess my specific question was how to calculate the correct size in this case (i.e. this question). [however noted that separate to this question moving forward should use another approach perhaps]

Comment: perhaps should accept this answer as answer question in general re why this is occuring, but not also try to find the "fix" as one should not be trying to obtain specific screen or widget sizes for canvas layout?

Comment: i think you need to elaborate more what you want to show eventually, cos as in the image, you can achieve it by setting appbar and simple container with padding in Scaffold with red background color